# How to build an array in React Native with Async Storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, arraylist, asyncstorage

I'm struggling to build an array with async storage in react native, all the tutorials and documents pages for async storage are very basic and don't provide much information past setting an item and then getting it, I'm new to programming and this is my first project so I'm struggling quite a bit

```
const Body = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [WorkoutsName, setWorkoutName] = useState();
  const [WorkoutSets, setWorkoutSets] = useState();
  const [WorkoutReps, setWorkoutReps] = useState();
  const [WorkoutWeight, setWorkoutWeight] = useState();

  let workoutSlide = [
    {
      name: WorkoutsName,
      sets: WorkoutSets,
      reps: WorkoutReps,
      weight: WorkoutWeight,
    }
  ]

  const load = async () => {
    try {
      const name = AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkoutName");
      const sets = AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkoutSets");
      const reps = AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkoutReps");
      const weight = AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkoutWeight");
      setWorkoutName(name);
      setWorkoutSets(sets);
      setWorkoutReps(reps);
      setWorkoutWeight(weight);
      console.log(workoutSlide);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }
  };
```

This is my attempt at creating an array so far but I keep getting an error on my emulator saying to create an array

```
const WorkoutTile = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [WorkoutsName, setWorkoutName] = useState();
  const [WorkoutSets, setWorkoutSets] = useState();
  const [WorkoutReps, setWorkoutReps] = useState();
  const [WorkoutWeight, setWorkoutWeight] = useState();

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("WorkoutName", JSON.stringify(WorkoutsName));
      AsyncStorage.setItem("WorkoutSets", JSON.stringify(WorkoutSets));
      AsyncStorage.setItem("WorkoutReps", JSON.stringify(WorkoutReps));
      AsyncStorage.setItem("WorkoutWeight", JSON.stringify(WorkoutWeight));

      navigation.navigate("Body");
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }
```

This is my workout page where I set the data with a text input, I want it similar to a ToDo list where I add a workout with the name, sets, reps and weight and that then creates a tile on the main page to display that data

At the moment when I set the data, it changes the data I originally input but only once I've reloaded the app with expo but I want it to add a new tile each time I add a new workout, I just can't seem to wrap my head around arrays

Comment: if you have any query or this answer won't help feel free to ask in comment section

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are on the right track with your attempt to create an array using AsyncStorage and update it in React Native. However, there are a few improvements and corrections needed in your code.

You can use the spread operator to maintain the previous array of slides and add a new one to it. This way, the new slide will be appended to the existing array without overwriting the previous values.

Below is a small snippet of the load function:

```
    const load = async () => {
    try {
      const name = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutName');
      const sets = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutSets');
      const reps = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutReps');
      const weight = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutWeight');

      if (name && sets && reps && weight) {
        setWorkoutSlides((prevSlides) => [
          ...prevSlides,
          {
            name: name,
            sets: sets,
            reps: reps,
            weight: weight,
          },
        ]);
      }
     } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
   };
```

here is a complete code snippet

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, View, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';

const Body = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [workoutSlides, setWorkoutSlides] = useState([]);

  const load = async () => {
    try {
      const name = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutName');
      const sets = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutSets');
      const reps = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutReps');
      const weight = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutWeight');

      if (name && sets && reps && weight) {
        setWorkoutSlides((prevSlides) => [
          ...prevSlides,
          {
            name: name,
            sets: sets,
            reps: reps,
            weight: weight,
          },
        ]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    load();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Your JSX for rendering workout slides */}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Body;

const WorkoutTile = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [WorkoutsName, setWorkoutName] = useState();
  const [WorkoutSets, setWorkoutSets] = useState();
  const [WorkoutReps, setWorkoutReps] = useState();
  const [WorkoutWeight, setWorkoutWeight] = useState();

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('WorkoutName', WorkoutsName);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('WorkoutSets', WorkoutSets);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('WorkoutReps', WorkoutReps);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('WorkoutWeight', WorkoutWeight);

      navigation.navigate('Body');
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Your JSX for input components and submission */}
    </View>
  );
};

export default WorkoutTile;
```

Comment: I am getting the error "property 'prevSlide' doesn't exist", I've tried to add it at the top of the page along with setWorkoutSlides but I'm getting no luck with it, any advice?

Comment: you make a typo mistake you have to type prevSlides not prevSlide also you don't need to define this anywhere in your code it's a parameter

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for persisting with me but I am still getting an error for the setWorkoutSlides, I have now copied your code exactly and I am getting the error "Could not find name 'setWorkoutSlides'. Did you mean 'setWorkoutSets'?" It also comes up with a render error saying that "Objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k}), If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

Comment: can you share your code with me only then i can help you by debugging what's wrong in it

Comment: i get it why you are getting that error becuase of this "let workoutSlide = [
    {
      name: WorkoutsName,
      sets: WorkoutSets,
      reps: WorkoutReps,
      weight: WorkoutWeight,
    }
  ]" you to create usesstate of workoutSlide

Comment: I have just adjusted it to have "const [WorkoutSlides, setWorkoutSlides] = useState();" as well but now I am getting an error saying "cannot convert undefined value to object"

Answer (score 0):

```css
const Workout = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [WorkoutsName, setWorkoutName] = useState();
  const [WorkoutSets, setWorkoutSets] = useState();
  const [WorkoutReps, setWorkoutReps] = useState();
  const [WorkoutWeight, setWorkoutWeight] = useState();

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {

      AsyncStorage.setItem("WorkoutName", JSON.stringify(WorkoutsName));
      AsyncStorage.setItem("WorkoutSets", JSON.stringify(WorkoutSets));
      AsyncStorage.setItem("WorkoutReps", JSON.stringify(WorkoutReps));
      AsyncStorage.setItem("WorkoutWeight", JSON.stringify(WorkoutWeight));
      navigation.navigate("Body");
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }

  };
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <View style={styles.Container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} maxLength={28} placeholder="Workout" onChangeText={value => setWorkoutName(value)}></TextInput>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} keyboardType="number-pad"
          maxLength={2}
          placeholder="Sets"
          onChangeText={value => setWorkoutSets(value)}></TextInput>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} keyboardType="number-pad" maxLength={2} placeholder="Reps" onChangeText={value => setWorkoutReps(value)}></TextInput>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} keyboardType="number-pad" maxLength={3} placeholder="Weight" onChangeText={value => setWorkoutWeight(value)}></TextInput>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSubmit}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add to Workout</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
```

```html
const Body = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [WorkoutsName, setWorkoutName] = useState();
  const [WorkoutSets, setWorkoutSets] = useState();
  const [WorkoutReps, setWorkoutReps] = useState();
  const [WorkoutWeight, setWorkoutWeight] = useState();
  const [prevSlides, setWorkoutSlides] = useState();


  const load = async () => {
    try {
      const name = AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkoutName");
      const sets = AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkoutSets");
      const reps = AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkoutReps");
      const weight = AsyncStorage.getItem("WorkoutWeight");
      setWorkoutName(name);
      setWorkoutSets(sets);
      setWorkoutReps(reps);
      setWorkoutWeight(weight);

      if (name && sets && reps && weight) {
        setWorkoutSlides((prevSlides) => [
          ...prevSlides,
          {
            name: name,
            sets: sets,
            reps: reps,
            weight: weight,
          },
        ]);
      }
      console.log(prevSlides)
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }
  };

  deleteWorkout = () => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("WorkoutName");
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("WorkoutSets");
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("WorkoutReps");
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("WorkoutWeight");
    setWorkoutName("");
    setWorkoutSets("");
    setWorkoutReps("");
    setWorkoutWeight("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    load();
  }, []);


  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
        <View style={styles.topItem}>
          <Text style={styles.workoutName}>WorkoutName</Text>
          <View style={styles.srwTitles}>
            <Text style={styles.workoutSets}>Sets</Text>
            <Text style={styles.workoutReps}>Reps</Text>
            <Text style={styles.workoutWeight}>Weight</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.workoutTile}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteWorkout}>
            <View style={styles.topItem}>
              <Text style={styles.workoutName}>{WorkoutsName}</Text>
              <View style={styles.srwTitles}>
                <Text style={styles.workoutSets}>{WorkoutSets}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.workoutReps}>{WorkoutReps}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.workoutWeight}>{WorkoutWeight}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
          <View style={styles.modalWeight}>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("AddWorkout")}>
              <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

These are my 2 pages, the setWorkoutSlides has an error message when I hover over it saying "Could not find name 'setWorkoutSlides'. Did you mean 'setWorkoutSets'?"

Comment: see above snippet i edited for you with complete sinppet check it and if you still get any error do let me know

Comment: In your body component define this sate and it should work perfectly fine "const [workoutSlides, setWorkoutSlides] = useState([]);" just above load function

Comment: I have just edited my code with the useState const and it is showing the error "Objects are not valid as a react child(found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: it's because you now need to use flatlist to render all data wait i'll provide you complete code

Comment: Any luck with the code mate?

Comment: I post a new answer with updated code i checked this and it's working fine just make a few changes in your and it'll work fine

Comment: If this works, then please do vote for my answers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the updated complete code of both components now style them and use them and modify them as you want

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Keyboard,
      TouchableWithoutFeedback,
      TextInput,
      FlatList,
    } from 'react-native';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
    
    const Workout = () => {
      const [WorkoutsName, setWorkoutName] = useState('');
      const [WorkoutSets, setWorkoutSets] = useState('');
      const [WorkoutReps, setWorkoutReps] = useState('');
      const [WorkoutWeight, setWorkoutWeight] = useState('');
    
      const onSubmit = async () => {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('WorkoutName', WorkoutsName);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('WorkoutSets', WorkoutSets);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('WorkoutReps', WorkoutReps);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('WorkoutWeight', WorkoutWeight);
        } catch (error) {
          alert(error);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              maxLength={28}
              placeholder="Workout"
              onChangeText={(value) => setWorkoutName(value)}
            ></TextInput>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              maxLength={2}
              placeholder="Sets"
              onChangeText={(value) => setWorkoutSets(value)}
            ></TextInput>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              maxLength={2}
              placeholder="Reps"
              onChangeText={(value) => setWorkoutReps(value)}
            ></TextInput>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textInput}
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              maxLength={3}
              placeholder="Weight"
              onChangeText={(value) => setWorkoutWeight(value)}
            ></TextInput>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSubmit}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add to Workout</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      );
    };
    
    const Body = () => {
      const [workoutSlides, setWorkoutSlides] = useState([]);
    
      const load = async () => {
        try {
          const storedSlides = await AsyncStorage.getItem('workoutSlides');
          if (storedSlides) {
            const parsedSlides = JSON.parse(storedSlides);
            setWorkoutSlides(parsedSlides);
          }
          const name = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutName');
          const sets = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutSets');
          const reps = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutReps');
          const weight = await AsyncStorage.getItem('WorkoutWeight');
          if (name && sets && reps && weight) {
            setWorkoutSlides((prevSlides) => [
              ...prevSlides,
              {
                name: name,
                sets: sets,
                reps: reps,
                weight: weight,
              },
            ]);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          alert(error);
        }
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        load()
      }, [])
      
      useEffect(() => {
        const storeData = async () => {
          try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('workoutSlides', 
    JSON.stringify(workoutSlides));
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        };
        storeData();
      }, [workoutSlides]);
    
      const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
        <View style={styles.workoutTile}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.topItem}>
              <Text style={styles.workoutName}>Work Out Name: {item.name} 
   </Text>
              <View style={styles.srwTitles}>
                <Text style={styles.workoutSets}>No. of Sets: {item.sets} 
   </Text>
                <Text style={styles.workoutReps}>No. of Reps: {item.reps} 
   </Text>
                <Text style={styles.workoutWeight}>Weight: {item.weight} 
   </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    
      return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <View style={styles.bodyContainer}>
            <FlatList
              data={workoutSlides}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      );
    };
    
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Workout />
          <Body />
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      // Add your styles here
    });
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: This actually works pretty well, thank you so much!! Just a couple of niggles though, how do I delete a workout? And also, when I create a new workout and navigate back to the original screen, I then have to refresh the app for the new data to show? Any ideas?

Comment: I've also just noticed as well that when I save or refresh, it always adds another workout slide with the last saved data on it so if I refresh 5 times without adding a new workout then I'll have 5 extra workout slides all with the same data?

Comment: you can delete item from an array by index here is a sample function you can use this "const deleteItem = async (index) => {
    try {
      const updatedSlides = workoutSlides.filter((item, i) => i !== index);
      setWorkoutSlides(updatedSlides);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('workoutSlides', JSON.stringify(updatedSlides));
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };" and for data load on navigate you have to use useisfocused hook to check when you component focused load data and on refreshing issue you might debug it

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look into the useIsFocused hook, I have just input your delete item function and it doesnt seem to do anything, I have added it to the onPress function on the TouchableOpacity inside renderItem, is this right?

Comment: It says that I can't vote until I get 15 reputation

Comment: You have to debug it